# Change CNAME to Active AWS Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, dns

I have an application running in AWS; both us-east-1 and us-west-2

When I have to perform maintenance or there is some other issue I want to switch DNS based on an nslookup.

I currently have two Jenkins jobs set up: east-to-west and west-to-east which requires me to manually verify the DNS record and pick the appropriate job. I now want to have a master job that will perform the nslookup then kick off the appropriate job.

I'm stuck trying to use the Jenkins conditional. If I do an "nslookup myapp | grep west" then I can trigger the west-to-east job. I'm not finding a way to do an, "else" if the condition is false.

Another option I'd consider is changing parameters as shown in the logic below and then doing a post build. My jobs names are flip-us-east-1-to-us-west-2 and flip-us-west-2-to-us-east-1

```
a=us-east-1
b=us-west-2

if nslookup east # if true will run us-west-2-to-us-east-1
  a=us-west-2
  b=us-east-1
fi

flip-a-to-b
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the new [Jenkins Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/). It should be pretty easy there to run a command (`sh` with `returnStdout: true`) and then trigger another job (`build`).

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline is an excellent idea but it's not installed :(

I ended up using a choice parameter which requires me to do the nslookup. I then do a string match conditional. Not ideal but works and boss is happy ;)